# How can I create a more-convenient hotkey for the Windows voice-typing feature?

Tags: windows, autohotkey

I am trying to make heavy use of Windows' voice-to-type feature and find the <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> hotkey to be less-than-ideal, because it isn't quick/easy to press with only my left hand when I have my right hand on the mouse (which is frequently the case because I'll normally have just clicked a text area/text box when I want to start dictating).

I tried creating an AutoHotkey key combination that would allow me to start the voice-to-type with just my left hand:

```
; Set "Ctrl + Shift + z" to "Windows + h" to start the Windows voice-to-type system.  It just makes it easier to reach.
^+z::Send #h
```

However, I'm very, very frequently having an issue where the voice-to-type window is behaving as if it had received two hotkey presses immediately after each other: it starts and the immediately stops the "I'm listening" mode. I can tell because it plays a sound when starting and stopping that mode, and it also plays an animation.

This issue *never* happens when I press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>.

Is there some way for me to stop this issue from happening? I'm wondering if maybe there's some way to modify the <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> hotkey through regedit or something.

### Things I've tried

I tried using the function mentioned in [this thread](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=55795) to prevent repeated key presses but the issue is still happening.

```
PreventRepeating() {
    KeyWait, Alt
    KeyWait, Ctrl
    KeyWait, Shift
    KeyWait, LWin
    KeyWait, RWin
    KeyWait, %A_ThisHotkey%
}

; Set Ctrl + Alt to Windows + h to start the Windows voice-to-type system.  It just makes it easier to reach.
^+z::
    Send #h
    PreventRepeating()
Return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an ***AutoHotkey*** solution and not a fix for the issue you experience with the AutoHotkey script. But how about a more "native" shortcut remapping solution?

I tried the [**Remap shortcut**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/keyboard-manager#remap-shortcuts) that is part of the ***Keyboard Manager utility*** in the [***Microsoft's PowerToys***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/) application, and it seems to be working perfectly fine.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this suggestion!  I had no idea this utility existed.  But I'm still seeing the same issue where it starts and immediately stops.  You're not having it happen?

Comment: No, I do not, maybe it's something else on your machine causing it. (Is the AutoHotkey maybe still running? Try stopping AutoHotkey completely.) With Windows+H you don't have this?

Comment: I've noticed something very interesting (I've got it working): with the original Windows + h hotkey, I can press the hotkey and then I don't need to keep any keys held down to have the 'listening mode' remain active; it stops listening automatically when it stops hearing me talking.  But when I remap the key, I need to keep all of the 'modifier keys' held down to keep the 'listening mode' active.  So for example if I'm using Win+z as the remapped shortcut, I need to keep the Windows key held down for the duration that I'm talking or the 'listening mode' will stop.  But it's working well enough

Comment: The modifier key-up events may be triggering the stop in that case. In autohotkey you can get around that sometimes by waiting for all the modifiers to release *before* sending, or triggering off of the hotkey up:: event, instead of using the standard hotkey definition (which triggers on the down event). This can result in a slightly 'lagged' feel for triggering the new hotkey, but it's usually not too bothersome in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternate approach you can use the below as it preserves your key functionality and is more versatile, although this is directly from the AHK documentation with some very basic altering of my own.

Source: [AHK Documentation #3](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/SetTimer.htm#ExampleCount)

```
#Persistent
#SingleInstance, Force

h::
if (Hotkey_Presses > 0)      ; ←←← SetTimer already started, so we log the keypress instead.
{
    Hotkey_Presses += 1
    Return
}
; ◦ ◦ ◦ ◦ ◦ ◦ ◦ Otherwise, this is the first press of a new series. Set count to 1 and start the timer.
Hotkey_Presses := 1
SetTimer, HotKey, -400   ; ←←← Wait for more presses within a 400 millisecond window.
    Return

HotKey:
if (Hotkey_Presses = 1)          ; ←←← The key was pressed once.
{
    Send, {TEXT}h
    Soundbeep, 1700, 150
}
else if (Hotkey_Presses = 2)         ; ←←← The key was pressed twice.
{
    SplashTextOn, 150, , The key was pressed twice.
    Soundbeep, 1700, 150
    Soundbeep, 1700, 150
        Sleep, 1500
    SplashTextOff
}
else if (Hotkey_Presses > 2)         ; ←←← Multiple key presses.
{
    SplashTextOn, 225, , The key was pressed three or more times.
    Soundbeep, 1700, 150
    Soundbeep, 1500, 150
    Soundbeep, 1900, 150
        Sleep, 1500
    SplashTextOff
}
; ◦ ◦ ◦ ◦ ◦ ◦ ◦ Regardless of which action above was triggered, reset the count to prepare for the next series of presses.
    Hotkey_Presses := 0
    Return

^Esc:: ExitApp
```

Comment: I suspect the Stack Exchange mods would probably prefer that you incorporate this into your original answer.

Comment: Apologies, was just trying to help and since they are two separate solutions they came as two separate answers.

Comment: Ok thank you for trying to help.  The accepted solution solves my problem well enough, but I just tried this out of curiosity.  I would argue that this *doesn't* preserve the original key functionality, because it introduces a 400ms delay before the key press registers.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this will help any, but have you considered just using a double tap as a hotkey? You wouldn't have to worry about how far apart the keys are and can make the hotkey whatever you want. Example provided lets you just double tap the 'H' key, but a single press does nothing for you so choose your key carefully. Of course you could also make it something like ^H:: (Ctrl+H) and retain your 'H' key functionality.

```
H:: 
If (A_ThisHotkey = A_PriorHotkey && A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < 250)    ; ←←← Double-Tap in less than 250 milliseconds.
SoundBeep, 2100, 100     ; ←←← To veryify double-tap success.
Return
```

Comment: So I just tried this, and interestingly enough, it's not having the issue that I report in my question, but I'm trying to find a key that will work well, because in the version that you have, it will never send the H key normally. I'm not sure how to modify your script to make it so that the key will work normally, but also has this double tap feature.

Comment: @Nathan Wailes, try replacing `H` by a modifier key (LControl, RControl, LShift, RShift, LAlt or RAlt) in the above code.